# How can I decide if I should use a NoSQL vs a SQL database engine?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I plan to build an app using Node.js as my Rest API Service and Angular for my Admin side.

I've tried to create Rest API using Node.js with MongoDB as my database server.

MongoDB is a transactional DB, not a relational DB. So my question is, is MongoDB not good as my database server because it's a transactional DB? (for storing all data let's say data for e-commerce)? How can I know which one to use, MongoDB or a regular SQL database.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think you mean Angular as your Front-End.

Comment: @AndrewLobban no no, it's my admin side, i have Fron-End using React

Comment: *"Thanks for your opinion"* - Perhaps you should read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) considering that *"What is your favorite...?"* is right up the top of the list of things not to ask and opinion based or essentially "too broad" questions really don't tend to live long around here. It really does not matter what other people think is "good enough" or "what your friend says" at all. All these things have different purposes and things they are "good at". It's really more about "what you need to do" and "what you are comfortable with".

Comment: AngularJS and mongo works nicely together. Node and mongo works nicely together. I think mongo is quirkier than SQL-alternatives, but if you haven't touched either it does not matter. It's crazy easy storing even the most complex json documents straight down from angular into mongo. I think of SQL as a excel-sheet with data (where you have to parse and sort stuff into each cell), and mongo as document-folders where you can dump your whole catalog of info. Which often makes SQL nicer when you have to retrieve the stuff again. Transactional or not does not play in much in my experience.

Comment: Thank you @ippi, your explanation start clearing my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of concepts wrong.

First, [Angular](https://angular.io/) is a frontend framework not a backend. Angular runs in the browser. Perhaps you mean you will use as your "admin" panel or whatever but it's a frontend technology. It will need to talk to an API server, which is the backend part.

Second, database engine selection is chosen depending on the system non-functional requirements. There are plenty of articles you can research so that **you** can make the decision, such as [this one](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/webinar-enterprise-data-management-in-the-era-of-mongodb-and-data-lakes) from MongoDB official site. There's also [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiOQyd8gx6c) on it too.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your answer, so i realy have a wrong concepts. I think that admin panel should connect to database directly, so what you mean is, admin panel should using Rest API to connect to database?

Comment: Correct. You **always** want any frontend app to use a API server before reaching the database, for security purposes. So, what you want here is for your angular app to also connect to your Node API server. Perhaps your admin endpoints will have an `/admin` prefix such as `/admin/customers` or `/admin/reports`